# How can I Insert html embed code in email

Tags: html, email

Does anybody know how to send embed code in a HTML email without the code being rendered.
I want to email the user a code that they can put on their website that shows that they are in the top 50 list on my site.
Here is an example of the code I'm trying to send:

```html
    <div style="display:inline-block;"><a href="http://google.com" target=_blank><img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo6w.png" width=250 border="0/"></a></div>
```

I tried sending it in a `textarea`, but `hotmail` replaced the `image src` with their image proxy URL.
So I need this code to stay the same.
Any ideas?
thanks.

Comment: Maybe use HTML entities for the angle brackets? &lt; &gt. I'm not very familiar with email, otherwise I'd put this down as an answer.

Comment: Ryan is correct. Just strip out the tags (replace with &lt; and &gt;) and it will render like standard text.

Comment: By the way, you have an error in the border width for the image.